# Sliding button [Ionic]

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

So how can I make a slide button like in the picture below using ionic framework ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Awesome question!!

In CSS or the web community in general it is called a Toggle button. According to ionic's official website, what you call it, will not get the results you are looking for.

Here is the official code snippet:

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="airplaneMode" toggle-class="toggle-calm">Airplane Mode</ion-toggle>
```

And here is the Official [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/tfAzj) that goes with it

And if you have anymore of these related questions you should check out the official [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/)!

Happy developing!

Edit:

What you are wanting I think isn't completely possible with ionic, if I find a better solution I will share, but I seem to be stumped now :/

Edit2: I am starting to conclude as bad as it seems, that this isn't but only common to e.g. IOS, but not finding it in any examples, just standard toggle buttons. The animation is done as though it was a checkbox. So essentially you are checking it. It just looks different. You may have to engineer this yourself. Again I will add a better solution if I find one, but as for now, I don't think there is a way to get it exactly as you wish.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i know all of this but i can't find a way to make it like the picture

Comment: Thanks for that feedback! so, you want it to look like that? Let me see what i can find!   I am having a hard time finding something like that exactly, so what i suggest- I will edit my answer xD with my suggestion.